# Ручной контроль над содержимым компонента React.js

Tags: reactjs

Как на React.js сделать компонент, содержимое dom-элемента которого должно полностью контролироваться скриптом?

Следующий код создаёт компонент `Smth`, представляющий из себя `div` с переданным тексом в качестве содержимого. Гарантируется, что в свойстве `text` будет строка.

```js
var Smth = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.div(this.props, this.props.text);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Smth, { 
    className: 'some-class',
    style: { color: 'blue' },
    text: "Some text goes here" // Nothing except text is here
  }),
  document.querySelector('main')
);
```

```css
.some-class {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: silver;
  float: left;
  padding: .25em .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.2.min.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Как сделать чтобы:

1. Реакт корректно строил и обновлял сам `div`.
2. Написанный скрипт полностью отвечал за содержимое этого div'а и мог помещать внутрь него как текст, так и разметку, а также изменять её независимо от компонента.
3. Написанный скрипт узнавал о том, что свойство `text` изменилось.
   Полагаю, что этот пункт должен выполняться сам собой.

Под *написанным скриптом* понимается некий скрипт внутри компонента, который не контролируется реактом. Есть потребность именно изменять содержимое dom-элемента независимо от реакта.

PS: [Этот же вопрос на английском.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33632643/4928642)

Comment: Ничего не понимаю. Все что вы описали, делается реактом из коробки. Надо обновлять элемент если приходит определенное значение, используйте `shouldComponentUpdate`. На все есть свои методы жизненного цикла компонента, а обновлять ту или иную вещь или нет, должны задавать Вы. Если надо например вернуть из реакта методы наверх, я на `componentWillMount` возвращал методы созданные внутри компонента, для управления им, например установка каких либо значений. И снаружи вызывал эти методы

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33632643/4928642

Answer (score 1):

[В документации](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/use-react-with-other-libraries.html) описывают работу со сторонними библиотеками.

Но нет ли смысла «сторонний скрипт» переписать как компонент React'а, реализующий этот `<div/>`?

Comment: Там полностью отключается обработака реакта: `shouldComponentUpdate: function() { return false; }`, а я хочу исключить её только для внутренностей. Хотя, на крайний случай поидёт.

Comment: По всем признакам вам от этого div'а требуется поведение просто очередного (вложенного) React-компонента. Точно ли логика *скрипта* несовместима с React'ом?

Comment: Логика скрипта содержит document.createRange для измерения размеров текста. А сам скрипт - это реализация многострочного эллипсиса - каждая строка оборачивается в span. Можно не меняя содержимое всё просчитать, а потом что-то нахимичить, чтобы реакт сам простроил желаемую структуру, но это не имеет смысла - на реакт сваливается лишняя и абсолютно бесполезная работа.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам нужно передавать содержимое для `<div />` через `React.DOM.div({dangerouslySetInnerHTML:{__html: '<span>your markup</span>'}})`.

[Документация](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)